# SAML role/permission

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml, saml-2.0

I'm using saml on my spring project. I did authentication but I couldn't use
role or permission part. I want do this. I can't find any example about
this.

Can you help me about this problem?

Best Regards ,
Ezgi

Answer (score 2):

Your IdP need to be configured to expose role information about this user, then SP could try to retrieve them from the Assertion. Is that what you want?

Comment: in fact, exactly, I want to sent user's role and permission from wso2 project to identity server. How can I send role/permission info from project to identity server?

Comment: You mean before authentication? Why you want to sent this?

Comment: Not before authentication, during the authentication. I want to this because, I want to open page according to role. So when the user authenticate username, pass and then get the role info from project, after I sent page according to this role.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Identity server won't accept these information. It is beyond the scope of SAML.

Comment: Ok, how about the openId? Can I use it for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about the requirement here, but for WSO2, sending the role information from IdP to SP requires configurations as mentioned [here](http://sureshatt.blogspot.in/2012/11/getting-user-claims-over-saml-sso-token.html).